# Remove empty lines in a text file via grep

Tags: linux, grep, text-processing

`FILE`:

```
hello

world

foo

bar
```

How can I remove all the empty new lines in this `FILE`?

Output of command:

`FILE`:

```
hello
world
foo
bar
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete empty lines using SED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414410/delete-empty-lines-using-sed)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

#### `grep . FILE`

---

(And if you really want to do it in sed, then: `sed -e /^$/d FILE`)

(And if you really want to do it in awk, then: `awk /./ FILE`)

Comment: Sweet! TY for the other commands as well - but looks like grep is my new best friend.

Comment: grep . FILE doesn't work for me. It's probably better to stick with grep for searching file contents, and sed for editing file contents.

Comment: a minor "issue" with grep . FILE is that if a space represents and blank line, then grep will grab that blank line as well.

Comment: `sed -ne/./p` works too, and `awk /./` is shorter (action is `{print}` if left unspecified).  @ghostdog74: `grep '[^[:space:]]'` then.

Comment: For those that don't understand, the `.` is a regular expression that matches any character except for newline.

Comment: `grep . FILE` works with the given example, but not necessarily when the file can have bytes not part of the charset. For instance, with GNU grep 2.20, `printf "\x80\n" | grep .` outputs nothing.

Comment: The downside of `grep .` compared to the other solutions is that it will highlight all the text in red. The other solutions can preserve the original colors. Compare `unbuffer apt search foo | grep .` to `unbuffer apt search foo | grep -v ^$`

Comment: `cat FILE | grep -v ^$` works fine. @wisbucky is right

Answer (score 51):

Try the following:

```
grep -v -e '^$'
```

Comment: this has the same effect as grep . FILE in that a space as a blank line will get grabbed.

Comment: "grep" looks for any line that matches the pattern.  "." matches any character.  "grep . FILE" matches any line with at least 1 character.  Whereas "grep -v" excludes lines matching the pattern.  OP said "remove all the empty new lines".  If you want to exclude lines with just spaces, "grep -v '^ *$'".  The "*" will match zero or more of the preceding pattern, in this case a space.  Though you might prefer to match and exclude other whitespace characters (tabs, form-feeds, etc) too.

Comment: BTW:  "^" matches beginning of line.  "$" matches the end of line.

Comment: This method allowed me to combine multiple excludes more easily than just "grep . FILE". For example, I was looking at a conf file and wanted to exclude all commented lines and all empty lines. So I used "grep -v -e '#' -e '^$' squid.conf". Worked a treat.

Comment: this one is a lot faster than the 'grep . FILE'. This is due to the more complex tasks of verifying the regex '.' than excluding as soon as ^$ does not matches.

Comment: `grep -v -e '^$'` always works, which is not the case of `grep .`. For instance, with GNU grep 2.20, `printf "\x80\n" | grep .` outputs nothing, while `printf "\x80\n" | grep -v '^$'` outputs the non-empty line.

Comment: _"PATTERN is, by default, a basic regular expression (BRE)"._ So `-e` option is not needed. For extended regular expressions `-E` option is needed.

Answer (score 13):

```
with awk, just check for number of fields. no need regex

$ more file
hello

world

foo

bar

$ awk 'NF' file
hello
world
foo
bar
```

Comment: Doesn't need quotes.  This trick is found in `awk1line.txt` -- then again, so are most awk tricks :)

Comment: its just my good practice to put quotes, since you are running it from shell.. for composite awk statements, you still have to put quotes. so why not cultivate this habit.

Comment: explanation of how this works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544804/how-awk-nf-filename-is-working

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution that removes all lines that are either blank or contain only space characters:

```
grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

If removing empty lines means lines including any spaces, use:

```
grep '\S' FILE
```

For example:

```
$  printf "line1\n\nline2\n \nline3\n\t\nline4\n" > FILE
$  cat -v FILE
line1

line2

line3

line4
$  grep '\S' FILE
line1
line2
line3
line4
$  grep . FILE
line1
line2

line3

line4
```

---

See also:

- [How to remove empty/blank lines (including spaces) in a file in Unix?](https://serverfault.com/q/252921/130437)
- [How to remove blank lines from a file in shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101440/21471)
- With `sed`: [Delete empty lines using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16414410/55075)
- With `awk`: [Remove blank lines using awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128328/21471)

Answer (score 4):

Simplest Answer -----------------------------------------

```
[root@node1 ~]# cat /etc/sudoers | grep -v -e ^# -e ^$
Defaults   !visiblepw
Defaults    always_set_home
Defaults    match_group_by_gid
Defaults    always_query_group_plugin
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
[root@node1 ~]#
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `sed -i '/^[ \t]*$/d' file-name`

It will delete all blank lines having any no. of white spaces (spaces or tabs) i.e. (0 or more) in the file.

Note: there is a 'space' followed by '\t' inside the square bracket.

The modifier `-i` will force to write the updated contents back in the file. Without this flag you can see the empty lines got deleted on the screen but the actual file will not be affected.

Answer (score 1):

`grep '^..' my_file`

example

```
THIS

IS

THE

FILE

EOF_MYFILE
```

it gives as output only lines with at least 2 characters.

```
THIS
IS
THE
FILE
EOF_MYFILE
```

See also the results with `grep '^' my_file` outputs

```
THIS

IS

THE

FILE

EOF_MYFILE
```

and also with `grep '^.' my_file` outputs

```
THIS
IS
THE
FILE
EOF_MYFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor))-way:

```
ex -s +'v/\S/d' -cwq test.txt
```

For multiple files (edit in-place):

```
ex -s +'bufdo!v/\S/d' -cxa *.txt
```

Without modifying the file (just print on the standard output):

```
cat test.txt | ex -s +'v/\S/d' +%p +q! /dev/stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl might be overkill, but it works just as well.

Removes all lines which are completely blank:

```
perl -ne 'print if /./' file
```

Removes all lines which are completely blank, or only contain whitespace:

```
perl -ne 'print if ! /^\s*$/' file
```

Variation which edits the original and makes a .bak file:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print if ! /^\s*$/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what the total lines of code is in your Xcode project and you are not interested in listing the count for each swift file then this will give you the answer.  It removes lines with no code at all and removes lines that are prefixed with the comment `//`

Run it at the root level of your Xcode project.

```
find . \( -iname \*.swift \) -exec grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' \+ | grep -v -e '//' | wc -l
```

If you have comment blocks in your code beginning with `/*` and ending with `*/` such as:

```
/*
 This is an comment block 
*/
```

then these will get included in the count.  (Too hard).