# How awk NF filename is working?

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following file:

```
cat testing.txt
==============
line1 1
line2 2 2


line3 3 3

line4
```

I can understand how the `awk 'NF > 0' testing.txt` working. This command is only processing the number of fields with more than 1 field from each record and thus empty lines and tabs are getting removed.

```
awk 'NF>0' testing.txt
line1 1
line2 2 2
line3 3 3
line4
```

However I cannot understand how the `awk NF testing.txt` is working. It is doing the same as above.

```
awk NF testing.txt
line1 1
line2 2 2
line3 3 3
line4
```

I am not specifying any condition in this case. Still it is working fine and removing empty lines and tab from each record.

I can see many references in Web where it is said we can use this command to remove empty lines or tabs from a file. Yet cannot understand the syntax.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`NF` stands for `N`umber of `F`ields. So whenever `NF` is bigger than 0, that `awk` interprets `True`. So in fact this is doing:

```
if NF>0  --> True
if NF==0 --> False
```

As the default behaviour of `awk` is `{print $0}`, this means that it does:

```
if NF>0   --->  True   ---> {print $0}
if NF==0  --->  False  ---> nothing
```

So `awk NF file` means: print all lines that have at least one field. Which automatically implies: print all no-empty lines.

Comment: Although I can't imagine a case where it would actually happen, it's probably considering `NF!=0` instead of strictly `NF>0`. A negative number of fields is most likely a non-issue, though... ;-)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just out of curiosity, I will leave it here to see if Ed Morton or another `awk` guru gives more light into this topic. I don't think it is possible, though : ) Thanks @twalberg !

Comment: `NF` variable is set when a line is read. Just like `1` results in printing the line, if `NF` has a value of `1` or greater (meaning a non-blank line, it translates as `awk 1 file` or `awk 23 file` depending on the value of `NF`, hence the printing of that line. If the line is blank, value of `NF` will be `0` and `awk 0 file` does no printing.

Comment: In case of `NF` From [gawk doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nonconstant-Fields.html): Negative field numbers are not allowed; trying to reference one usually terminates the program. (The POSIX standard does not define what happens when you reference a negative field number. gawk notices this and terminates your program. Other awk implementations may behave differently.)

Comment: This solution doesn't work with Windows line endings, i.e. `\r\n` However this solution works for both UNIX and Windoze line endings:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432555/remove-blank-lines-with-grep